# Prevent navigating after link click in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to use tinymce to show and edit html code. I also want to let the user edit hyperlinks. But I want a special handling: I want to know if a link is clicked but I don't want to navigate.
I tried this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    plugins: 'link',
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('init', function() {
        editor.setContent('<h1>My heading</h1><a href="page.html">This is a link</a>');
        editor.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
          if (e.currentTarget.nodeName == 'a') {
            alert('clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

The editor is loaded correctly but if I click the link then I will get a "File not found".

Comment: TinyMCE does not navigate to a link when clicked.  Clicking on a link does nothing and right clicking opens a context menu to manipulate the link.  What are you trying to accomplish and why is the default behavior not appropriate?

Comment: Hm, that's curious. For example if I press the space bar or enter key on the link, it's navigating...

Comment: That is not the default behavior for TinyMCE.  What version are you running?

Comment: I'm currently running the TinyMCE Community 4.6.1.

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle or CodePen that shows this happening?  There has to be something specific in your setup that is causing links to be clickable as this is not the default TinyMCE behavior.

Comment: I fear this will not help you. The test page is the one you see above. Can it be that it is a problem because I have mixed tinymce and jquery?